# dimple.js problems using frameValue to stop storyboard flow

Tags: javascript, storyboard, dimple.js

The default behavior for a storyboard in dimple.js is to re-run indefinitely. I would like my storyboard to stop after one run-through.

I tried doing this by setting the onTick function like so:

```
  myStoryboard.onTick = function (e) {
      if (e.frameValue == "40") {
      myStoryboard.stopAnimation();
      }
  };
```

The basic idea works, but I cannot get the "e.frameValue == 40" conditional to ever evaluate to true. I've tried +e.frameValue == 40, +e.framevalue > 40, e.framevalue> 40, and none of them catch.

If I simply do something like "3 < 4", it works, stopping the animation after the first tick.

My storyboard uses the "Day" dimension, which runs from 1 to 50 in my data file.

What do I need to do for the conditional inside the if to be triggered to stop the animation?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting `console.log(e.frameValue)` in there and seeing what comes out?  If so can you share the results?  Of course if frameValue is "40" then your code will work which suggests frameValue is not 40.  You're usage is correct according to the docs so maybe there is a bug.  You could also try `myStoryboard.getFrameValue()` if there is a problem with the event arguments.

Comment: When I use console.log(e.frameValue), firefox displays a number counting up from 1. So that does not appear to be the issue. Using myStoryboard.getFrameValue() worked, thanks! Maybe there is a bug or just a needed clarification in the documentation.